# My request for data from server using the XMLHttpRequest, keeps returning undefined

Tags: json, ajax, server, xmlhttprequest, undefined

I tried to request data from this server address `https://codexpression.github.io/catz/catz.json`  using AJAX XMLHttpRequest, but when I tried to `console.log` the property value of the text, I keep getting "undefined", please find code below:

```js
function getData() {
  let requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();            //create XMLHttpRequest Object

  requestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {      //create an onstatechange function
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  //check if request is successful
      // myFunction(this)
      let convert = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
      console.log(convert.all.text)
    }
  };

  requestObject.open("GET", "https://codexpression.github.io/catz/catz.json", true); //get the document address and send request
  requestObject.send()
}

getData()
```

Comment: `console.log(convert)` will show you what that parsed object look like & you can further debug it from there

Comment: @Shan it keeps returning undefined in the console even with alert also

Comment: `console.log(convert)`  
i'm getting back an array of cat info so the API & your code definitely works, `convert.all` is an array

Comment: Wow thanks @Shan i didnt even check, i just assumed its an object, used the dot notation to access the values, and its working just fine